# UDF Javascript not called from HTML button onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I've been through it all looking high and low for an answer. I've tried almost everything I found during the last 11 hours to no avail. Here is my problem:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="xp2bank(100, 'att')">click</button> does not work,
```

HOWEVER,

```
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('this works')">click</button> does work.
```

What I am trying to do is make a UDF that can be called from many buttons by passing parameters to the function (It would be nice to know if there is an easier way of doing this.) The purpose of the function will be to update elements of $fetch[] based upon the value chosen after a check to insure their is enough held in either $fetch['bank_###'] or $fetch['exp_#####'] depending upon the users choice. Once the change is made the code will update the appropriate cell. When the user is done there will be a button to save their changes at which time the table will be updated. The rest of the code will be a cake walk in the park once I get over this hurtle.

My code is not pretty or commented yet, I've been in it so much I figure when I get it right I will make it pretty and well commented.

below is a revised shortened snippet of the code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>

      function bank2xp(howmuch, skill){
        switch(skill) {
            case 'att':
              alert('Attack ' + howmuch);
         }
      }

      function xp2bank(howmuch, skill){
        alert('Attack ' + howmuch);


      } 
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
                <table class='table table-bordered'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th colspan="2">Priamary Combat Stats</th>
                          <th style="text-align: right" colspan="2">Banked XP: (value from array)</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th >Stat</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">Level</th>
                            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: right">Experiance Points</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Attack</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">(value from array)</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">(value from array)</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center" colspan="2">Send to bank</br>
                          <button type="button" onclick="xp2bank(100, 'att')">100</button>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center" colspan="2">Add from bank</br>
                          <button type="button" onclick="bank2xp(100, 'att')">100</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm really not clear what the problem is here. You need to provide a [mcve]. If the problem is that the JS isn't being called, then you should be able to demonstrate that with a single button and the JS. You shouldn't need all the masses of table markup, the other buttons or any PHP.

Comment: I have read an uncountable number of comments today (yesterday) that stated to show the code and how you are doing it. NO WHERE did I read any comments about providing a snippet or small demonstration code. Therefore I provided the CODE. .

Comment: Well, now you have. Providing an [mcve] will make it easier for people to help you. If it is easier, then people are more likely to provide that help. Which you aren't paying anything for.

Comment: N.b. You should accept the answer and also it's not a good idea to edit the posted snippet to fix the original problem, so that people can see what is going on. not a big deal on this post but for future reference.

Comment: I agree that editing makes more difficult to follow up the thread, and my original intention was writing a new answer with a new snippet, but then an automated warning showed up, and suggested me to edit my first answer instead of writing a new one.
I guess I am weak person that can be influenced even by a machine... :cry
Ty for the advice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found it...

```
function xp2bank(howmuch, skill)( ... )
```

It should be:

```
    function xp2bank(howmuch, skill){ 
switch(skill) {
  case 'att':
    alert('Attack ' + howmuch);
    break;
  case 'str':
    // ...
    break;
  case 'def':
    // ...
    break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Well, I tried to edit the post with a 58 liner snippet to no avail. And it seems that I am now banned from asking questions. LOL, my first post and someone decides to hit the button.

Comment: Thank you Arampg, I tried that in both the source and the snippet. Neither worked. I really don't understand how calling alert from on onclick works and calling a udf from another don't. I need to find a way around this or steam roll through it.

Comment: Check your code inside the function. Switch/Case structure should be like: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch

And someone downvoted us, I don't really know why. I upvoted you, check if you can know edit your question.

Comment: I was able to revise the posted code, thank you for your help. Even with the stripped down version it still does not work. If it works else where then maybe I have an issue with my local host and server.

Comment: Check snippet answer now, and apply changes to your code, you will see it works.

Edit typo.

Comment: YES IT DOES, the problem was the switch/case statement. I had it wrong. Thank you Arampg for showing me the way. I can go to bed now that it is 4:35am and i been at these from 7 yesterday morning. Thank you again.

Comment: You would have solved it yourself after some rest, as well xD

Comment: Glad that you have been able to solve this. Please accept this answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I beg you to forgive me, but I didn't check your code. What I did is to isolate what you think it is not working, to prove that it should work.

```js
function xp2bank(howmuch, skill){ 
  switch(skill) {
    case 'att':
      alert('Attack ' + howmuch);
      break;
    case 'str':
      alert('Strentgh ' + howmuch);
      break;
    case 'def':
      alert('defence ' + howmuch);
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="xp2bank(100, 'att')">Attack 100</button>
<button type="button" onclick="xp2bank(1000, 'str')">Strentgh 1,000</button>
<button type="button" onclick="xp2bank(50, 'def')">Defence 50</button>
```

Edited snippet.